# How can I get responses via Gmail?

Tags: c#, gmail

I am currently sending out an e-mail via Gmail in C# with a simple question such as 'Did you go to class today?'

I want the person to be able to respond with a YES or NO in some fashion, however, I am unsure as to how to do it and then retrieve it in C#.

Aside from having them type in the response, is there any other way to do this?

Comment: You can include links in the email which point back to a web application that you control.  Users can simply click on the link as a "response" and your web application can track those requests.

Comment: Either make a link to a web server you control, or use a service like Mailgun that will send HTTP requests to your server when it receives email.

Comment: It sounds to me like this C# program is a simple desktop application and not an ASP.NET project, so links might not be possible under the current model.  He could use an IMAP client to read responses...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to embed two links into the email.  The yes link and the no link.

When the user clicks on one of these links it directs them to a webpage you have created which records the response. The link can included the 'id' of the student and their response in query string parameters.

Comment: Thank you James.  How does a link include the 'id' and then how do I get it that 'id' out in C#?

Comment: simple way is to use querystrings like "http:www.myresponse.com?response=yes".  You can reference that querystring in the codebehind of the webpage you are linking to.

Comment: B-Rad - you'll need to write (and host) a very basic web app.  There are lots of tutorials on setting up a simple asp.net MVC web app.  Once you've get the template up and running reading in a query string parameter is as simple as using its name as a parameter on the action. But this won't mean anything unless you've got some basic idea of how asp.net MVC works - for which I'd follow the aforementioned tutorials.